# jQuery simple: two functions colliding

Tags: jquery

It's about the "Contato" item on menu. When you click it, it toggles height popping up and down the divs. Works fine. Plus that, I wanted to put an "X" button.

The problem is: when I click on "Contato", it pops up. I click on the X and it pops down. But if I click on "Contato" again, it only works if I do it twice.

Do you guys have any idea on how I can improve my poor jQuery to fix this problem?

this is live on:
http://www.arthurfalcao.com.br

```
<section id="contato">
            <article id="info">
                <p>21 8668 1419</p>
                <p>22 7836 4351</p>
                <p>87*146596</p>
                <a href="mailto:artfalcao@gmail.com" title="E-mail para contato" target="_blank">artfalcao@gmail.com</a>
            </article>
            <div class="contato">
                <span class="close">X</span>
                <?php echo do_shortcode("[si-contact-form form='1']"); ?>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script>
            jQuery("#menu-item-21 a").click(function () {
                jQuery(this).toggleClass("black");
            });
            jQuery("#menu-item-21").toggle(function(){
                jQuery("#contato").animate({height:375},600);
                jQuery("#info").animate({height:0},700);},
                function(){
                jQuery("#contato").animate({height:150},600);
                jQuery("#info").animate({height:115},700);
            });

        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery(".close").click(function () {
                jQuery('#contato').animate({height:150},700);
                jQuery("#info").animate({height:115},700);
            });
            jQuery("#menu-item-21 a").click(function () {
                jQuery(this).removeClass("black");
            });         
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
       jQuery(".close").click(function () {
            jQuery('#contato').animate({height:150},700);
            jQuery("#info").animate({height:115},700);
        });
```

to

```
       jQuery(".close").click(function () {
            jQuery('#menu-item-21').trigger('click');
        });
```

The problem you are having is due to your use of `.toggle`. Right now if you click the X it animates closed, but does not effect the `.toggle` state. Instead, have the X trigger a click on `#menu-item-21`, that way its using `.toggle` and effecting the toggle state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution AND explanation of the problem, it worked perfectly.